# What is the best way to structure excel tables when reading into a pandas multi-index?

Tags: pandas, excel, multi-index

When structuring data in excel for use as a multi-index in python pandas, what is the best way to structure the data in excel. I'm currently querying data from Bloomberg in time series format in excel.

I use pandas to get the table in multi-index format but the columns for Date are filled with    Unnamed: 1_level_10 etc.

Below is my pandas script:
`pd.read_excel(xls,'Sheet1', header=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],index_col=0)`

Below is the excel table structure I have used (hypothetical example below).

I appreciate any thoughts on what is the best structure from excel to python pandas as it seems most data is time series form.

| Sector | Construction | Construction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sub-sector | Residential | Residential |
| Category | Residential_housing | Residential_housing |
| Sub-category | Permits | Completions |
| Country | France | USA |
| Unit | number | number |
| Ticker | TICK Index | TICK2 Index |
| Description | total_resi_house_permits_FR | total_resi_house_completions_US |
| Date |  |  |
| 2023/01/31 | 599 | 800 |
| 2023/02/28 | 650 | 820 |
| 2023/03/31 | 620 | 875 |

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close, only need remove last row `8`, because there is no header:

```
df = pd.read_excel(xls,'Sheet1', header=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Test output:

```
print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-31', '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31'], 
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date ', freq=None)

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('Construction ', 'Residential ', 'Residential_housing ', ...),
            ( 'Construction',  'Residential',  'Residential_housing', ...)],
           names=['Sector ', 'Sub-sector ', 'Category ', 'Sub-category ',
                  'Country ', 'Unit ', 'Ticker ', 'Description '])

print (df.to_numpy())
[[599 800]
 [650 820]
 [620 875]]
```

---

```
print (df.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3 entries, 2023-01-31 to 2023-03-31
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column                                                                                                                      Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                                                                                                                      --------------  -----
 0   (Construction , Residential , Residential_housing , Permits , France , number , TICK Index , total_resi_house_permits_FR )  3 non-null      int64
 1   (Construction, Residential, Residential_housing, Completions, USA, number, TICK2 Index, total_resi_house_completions_US)    3 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 72.0 bytes
None
```